# findOneByIdAndUpdate mongodb and express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to wrote RESTFull api with express and mongodb  . sections for registraion and login are work properly but when I trying to updatOneById it dosent work .and send you can update only uor accout i delete if cluse but it still same and doesnt work  .
**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");


dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  }
);

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);


app.listen(8800, () => {
  console.log("Backend server is running!");
});
```

and these are my routers

first is Auth.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //generate new password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    //create new user
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    //save user and respond
    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
});

//LOGIN
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    !user && res.status(404).json("user not found");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    !validPassword && res.status(400).json("wrong password")

    res.status(200).json(user)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**seconde is user router**

```
const User = require("../models/User");
const router = require("express").Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//update user
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.userId === req.params.id || req.body.isAdmin) {
    if (req.body.password) {
      try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
      } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    }
    try {
      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $set: req.body,
      });
      res.status(200).json("Account has been updated");
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You can update only your account!");
  }
});

//delete user
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.userId === req.params.id || req.body.isAdmin) {
    try {
      await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
      res.status(200).json("Account has been deleted");
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You can delete only your account!");
  }
});

//get a user
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    const { password, updatedAt, ...other } = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json(other);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//follow a user

router.put("/:id/follow", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.userId !== req.params.id) {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
      const currentUser = await User.findById(req.body.userId);
      if (!user.followers.includes(req.body.userId)) {
        await user.updateOne({ $push: { followers: req.body.userId } });
        await currentUser.updateOne({ $push: { followings: req.params.id } });
        res.status(200).json("user has been followed");
      } else {
        res.status(403).json("you allready follow this user");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(403).json("you cant follow yourself");
  }
});

//unfollow a user

router.put("/:id/unfollow", async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.userId !== req.params.id) {
      try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.body.userId);
        if (user.followers.includes(req.body.userId)) {
          await user.updateOne({ $pull: { followers: req.body.userId } });
          await currentUser.updateOne({ $pull: { followings: req.params.id } });
          res.status(200).json("user has been unfollowed");
        } else {
          res.status(403).json("you dont follow this user");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(403).json("you cant unfollow yourself");
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

**and this is my schema model **

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 20,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max: 50,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 6,
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    coverPicture: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    followers: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    followings: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      max: 50,
    },
    city: {
      type: String,
      max: 50,
    },
    from: {
      type: String,
      max: 50,
    },
    relationship: {
      type: Number,
      enum: [1, 2, 3],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I find that .all of my code is ok but the problem is my cluster on mongodb.

you have to  delete your  cluster and run it again  the problem will be solved .